# What is the best practice to make a div into a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a little issue here. I've got a `div` with `h1, h2 and p`. I want to make the div into a link, but I can't just wrap a `<a>` around a div or h1, h2, p. That's not the correct way, but what should I do to make the whole div into a link?
Should I make every element into a `span`? This would require a lot more work

```
<a href="#" class="link">
    <span class="div">
        <span class="h1"></span>
        <span class="h2"></span>
        <span class="p"></span>
    </span>
</a>
```

or should I use javascript:

```
$('.link').click(function(){
   document.location.href='#';
})
```

Comment: In html5 it's allowed http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/a.html#a-changes

Comment: Just use CSS, you don't need any JS to accomplish this. Don't overcomplicate things ^^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your original HTML looks something like the below, you should add a `data` parameter containing the link to follow when the div is clicked:

```
<div class="link" data-url="http://www.google.com">
    <span class="div">
        <span class="h1"></span>
        <span class="h2"></span>
        <span class="p"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Then you can attach a `click` handler to the `div`:

```
$('.link').click(function() {
    window.location.assign($(this).data('url'));
});
```

Finally, make sure to add the `cursor` attribute in CSS so it's obvious that the div is clickable:

```
.link { cursor: pointer; }
```

Comment: Why not use `href` instead of `data-url`?

Comment: but should I change the h1, h2, p into spans? or just use javascript to select the div?

Comment: @Chanckjh it's not needed then.

Comment: @JanDvorak because `div` elements do not have a `href` attribute. Adding one would make the page invalid.

Comment: just my two cents: beware that the "links" won't be visible neither to search engines nor to browsers/users with javascript turned off (accessibility!). So I usually add a real link (a href) inside the div and occasionally make it invisible through css.

Comment: There's no need to use any JS to do this at all. You can even still us h1, h2 and p tags like the OP wants.

Answer (score 11):

You don't need any JS or jQuery to do this. An alternative would be to do something like this:

```
<div>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <h1>Something</h1>
    <h2>Something else</h2>
    <p>Another something</p>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
    div {
        position: relative;
    }

    div > a {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 2;
    }
</style>
```

Of course, change the CSS selectors so that they only affect whatever you want them to affect. The advantages of this are of course if the user doesn't have JS enabled, it will still completely work normally, and it's better for SEO.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div onclick="window.location = 'http://www.abc.com/';" style="cursor:pointer;">

</div>
```

Comment: Since jQuery is available, why not use it? Also, don't use inline styles.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on what Rory has proposed I think it might be safter to incude an actual link inside your div incase the user does not have javascript enabled and for search engine indexing.

```
<div class="link">
  <h1><a href="http://www.google.com">Heading One</a></h1>
  <h2>Heading Two</h2>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Then search for the h1 link and use that as the url

```
$('.link').on('click', function() {
    window.location = $(this).find('h1 a').attr('href');
});
```

And the CSS

```
.link { cursor:pointer; }
```

Answer (score 0):

In HTML5 (2023)

The `<a>` element can be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables, and so forth, even entire sections, so long as there is no interactive content within (e.g., buttons or other links). This example shows how this can be used to make an entire advertising block into a link:

```
<aside class="advertising">
 <h1>Advertising</h1>
 <a href="https://ad.example.com/?adid=1929&amp;pubid=1422">
  <section>
   <h1>Mellblomatic 9000!</h1>
   <p>Turn all your widgets into mellbloms!</p>
   <p>Only $9.99 plus shipping and handling.</p>
  </section>
 </a>
 <a href="https://ad.example.com/?adid=375&amp;pubid=1422">
  <section>
   <h1>The Mellblom Browser</h1>
   <p>Web browsing at the speed of light.</p>
   <p>No other browser goes faster!</p>
  </section>
 </a>
</aside>
```

Source: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element